# Jquery ui dialog widget with tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs, jquery-dialog

I'm looking for a JQuery widget mixing dialog and tabs. The idea is to have the close in the same line as the tabs and an option for the ok/cancel buttons. There is an old entry in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4317975/763790), but it's not working properly with the latest Jquery UI version - 1.8.

By any chance and before doing my own version, does somebody want to share an existing solution ?

----- UPDATE -------------

The answer from Didier works fine, I modified his answer to add buttons and change the button to a jquery icon and create a jquery-ui widget -> here is the [code/example](http://jsfiddle.net/2a7z2/2/).

If somebody finds how to move the hard-coded css to the actual css it would be welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed the example in the link you gave but implemented in another way:

You can add a `<li>` in the tabs buttons markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-info">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-cast">Cast List</a></li>
    <li class="ui-tabs-close-button"><button id="closeBtn">X</button></li>
</ul>
```

I have used here a `<button>` but you can have another type of element. You could use an anchor tag but the Tabs plugin considers it as a possible tab button and if it cannot do anything with it, it creates a disabled tab, which makes it a bit harder to undo.

Then, bind a click event on the `<button>` in the create event of the Tabs to close the dialog:

```
$('#tabs-movie').tabs({
    create: function(e, ui) {
        $('#closeBtn').click(function() {
            $('#dialog-movie-info').dialog('close');
        });
    }
});
```

With this piece of CSS you can put the close button right-side:

```
.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-close-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/HTJ4z/)**

---

Here's the css to apply to remove the hard-coded css styles:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
    margin: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 0.4em;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/dNyYQ/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer, a question, is there a rational why the tabs are created 'on open' and not 'on creation' of the dialog ?

Comment: I just took the example from your link, but you can use the "create" event of the dialog to initialize the tabs for sure ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Pn9HM/)).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just modified your example to add buttons and change the icon (I updated the question), just a little trouble with the css

Comment: Thanks for great, do you think it's possible putting the header draggable for the dialog (I'm abusing a bit I know) ?

Comment: I got it, just put draggable on the parent's div with the correct handle (strange needing the parent's of the dialog widget). I owe you one in case you need it, who knows :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the button in the `dialog` open function:

```
open: function() {
    var li = $('<li />').append($(this).siblings().find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css('float', 'right').detach());
    $('#tabs-movie').tabs();
    $('#tabs-movie ul.ui-tabs-nav').append(li);
},
```